# Python logging objects

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to reformat the output data sent to the logger based on it's class.

For example:

- strings will be printed as they are
- dictionaries/lists will be automatically indented/beautified into html
- my custom classes will be handled on an individual basis and converted to html

My problem is that the message sent to the formatter is always a string. The documentation specifically says that you can send objects as messages, but it seems to be converting the objects to strings before I can format them.

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def format(self, record):
        #The problem is that record.message is already a string...
        ...
```

Where is the appropriate place for me to handle objects sent as messages?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I've figured it out.

The documentation in the official docs is a little bit unclear, but basically, there are two attributes

LogRecord.message -> a string representation of the message
and 
LogRecord.msg -> the message itself.

To get the actual object, you must reference the .msg for it to work.

I hope this was useful to someone else.

Comment: The LogRecord should not contain a .message except if it has been  formatted by the default Formatter (or a costum Formatter that adds a .message). Perhaps either you have a multiple handler or you are calling the Formatter.format(record) from your derived function, which should be unnecessary?

Comment: You are correct. I'm not explicitly calling the parent classes format(), however, I haven't overridden the default __init__, so I suspect that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the `__str__()` method of the objects you are logging?